# How to collapse multiple rows into one row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I currently have a dataframe that has three rows and 10 columns. Every column only has one value in it. Here is what it looks like:

> 

```
Segment               1        2       3  ...      8       9      10
MaxST1 - ST2-V   33.7507   -.----  -.---- ... 16.3022  -.---- -.----
ZeroST1 - ST2-V   -.----   -.----      0  ...  -.----      0       0
MissST1 - ST2-V   -.----   68.5865  -.---- ...  -.----  -.----  -.----
```

Row 1 (Max) will only ever have floats or hyphens.
Row 2 (Zero) will only ever have 0s or hyphens.
Row 3 (Miss) will only ever have nulls or hyphens (no null values pictured, hence all hyphens).

All I want to do is collapse the rows so that I have one row with integers, 0s, and nulls, and I want to rename the row to be something different (subject number, which is another variable that I already created in my code).

***Edited: I applied some of the suggestions below, and they were helpful, though my issue isn't completely solved.***

Here's the problem: I want to keep the 0s in the "zero" row as the number 0. I want integers in the 'miss' column be converted to NaN. And the kicker: I need to sum the columns, and the value should either be an integer, a zero, *or a null*. This has made figuring out how to sum into one row very difficult.

The .sum() function is telling me that NaN+integer = NaN
and that 0+integer = nothing at all. I am confused! I don't know how to achieve the summed row that I want!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First use `.fillna()` to replace all the null values with `0`. Then you can sum each column.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data with `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: `Out[42]: 
{1: {'MaxST1 - ST2-V': '33.7507',
  'ZeroST1 - ST2-V': '-.----',
  'MissST1 - ST2-V': '-.----'},
 2: {'MaxST1 - ST2-V': '68.5865',
  'ZeroST1 - ST2-V': '-.----',
  'MissST1 - ST2-V': '-.----'},
 3: {'MaxST1 - ST2-V': '-.----',
  'ZeroST1 - ST2-V': 0,
  'MissST1 - ST2-V': '-.----'},
 4: {'MaxST1 - ST2-V': '62.9095',
  'ZeroST1 - ST2-V': '-.----',
  'MissST1 - ST2-V': '-.----'},
 5: {'MaxST1 - ST2-V': '29.2125',
  'ZeroST1 - ST2-V': '-.----',
  'MissST1 - ST2-V': '-.----'})`

Answer (score 1):

It will be more precise if you use jupyter notebook.
Well, If I understand, you want a column that has only integer values and other column that has only zeros(0), and another column with null values.

1. Please, make sure the type of data in your data frame: object, int64, float64, etc.
2. Cast the categorical data to numeric one, if needed,
3. Then, you can separate column data.

Sorry, I could not understand the view of you data frame, so I cannot give specific approach. If you can share the picture of dataframe in more precise way, then community or I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I guess to see, your dataframe consists of strings (-.---).

I would do then the following.

```
# Here everything shall be converted in numbers, -.--- will be set to NaN with the setting coerce
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Then a row will be added with the sum of each column
df.loc['sum']=df.sum()
```

Comment: If you then add the line `df = df.dropna()` it will remove the 'old' rows which will collapse the rows as the OP describes.